# Is there a connection between renormalisation and scaling of the metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, renormalization, quantum-gravity

In renormalisation, we work things out down a certain scale $\Lambda$ using a theory with coupling constants which depend on this cut-off scale.

But if we change coordinates by scaling the metric $g^{\mu\nu}(x)$ by a factor $\alpha$ this will scale the cut-off scale.

Worse, if the metric scales differently at place to place, then a theory in one coordinate system with a cutoff scale $\Lambda$ would have a position dependent cut-off scale $\Lambda(x)$ when done with a different metric.

So from this argument it seems like a quantum theory of gravity must have a connection between the metric field $g^{\mu\nu}(x)$ and the renormalisation cut-off scale $\Lambda$.

Or to put it another way, if you chose a different cut-off scale at different places when doing for example QCD calculations, this sounds like it would be equivalent to doing those calculations in the presence of a gravitational field. (Although it's not clear how you would change the lattice size from place to place!)

Or to put it a third way, it seems like a gravitational field would alter the coupling constants. (e.g. could the electromagnetic constant 1/137 be different on the Moon than on Earth?)

Are any of these deductions correct?

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Dimensional regularization rather than cut-off regularization is the preferred choice when it comes to look at pure gravity's one-loop corrections. This is because this scheme doesn't tamper with diffeomorphism invariance of general relativity. You yourself demonstrated it nicely in your question by imposing cut-off regularization, where the classical symmetry is no longer preserved.

The one-loop calculation done by [t'Hooft and Veltman](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPA_1974__20_1_69_0.pdf) utilized this technique to get a nice result for pure gravity. [These notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9512024) might be helpful as well.

The basic problem with these calculations is that at higher loops, you would need increasing number of counterterms to absorb all divergences. One can see that from the mass dimension of Newton's constant in the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian.

Comment: regularization $\neq$ renormalization

Comment: @mmeent Notice the way OP phrased the question. It appears their $\Lambda$ is the cutoff regulator. In any case, I mentioned the standard method to do 1-loop calculations, and get the counterterms.

Comment: I suspect they is referring to a renormalization scale.

Comment: @mmeent In that case, again, do dimreg, get counterterms by enforcing the renormalization conditions at that scale (as t'Hooft and Veltman did). They can compute the beta function to one loop afterwards if they want to look at the flow of couplings. Thanks for pointing this out.